# Logstash receive strange "<133>" code at the start of receiving TrendMicro log

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

My Logstash server is CentOS Linux release 8.1.1911.
logstash.version"=>"7.7.0"

I have a capture of what I received on port UDP 5514 with :

`nc -lvu 5514 -o log.txt`

The content of log.txt

> <133>Jun 05 09:23:35 TMCM:EVT_URL_CONTENT_FILTERING Security product="OfficeScan" Security product node="N/A" Security product IP="xx.xx.xx.xx;xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:4490" Event time="4/25/2020 11:46:01 PM (UTC)" URL="http://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.intranet/SMS_MP/.sms_pol?DEP-Z0120115-ScopeId_B14503FF-F7AA-49EC-A38C-F50D813EEC6E/Application_57a673e1-3e65-4f1c-8ce2-0f4cc1b38acc.SHA256:5EF20484EEC38EA203D7A885EAA48BE2DFDC4F130ED8BF5BEA333378875B2516" Source IP="" Destination IP="yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy" Policy rule="" Blocking type="Web reputation" Domain="xxxx-xxxxx" Event time (local)="4/25/2020 7:46:01 PM" Client host name="N/A" Reputation Score="81"`

myfilter.conf

```
input
{
    udp
    {
      port => 5514
      type => syslog
    }
}

filter
{
     grok
     {
        match =>
         { "message" => "(?<user_agent>[^>]*)(?<user_agent>[^:]*)%{POSINT}\s%{WORD:logfrom}\s%{WORD:logtag}\:\s%{NOTSPACE:eventname}\s([^=]*)\=%{QUOTEDSTRING:security_product} ([^=]*)\=%{QUOTEDSTRING:security_prod_node}\s([^=]*)\=\"%{IPV4:security_prod_ip}([^=]*)\=\"(?<agent_detected_time>%{MONTHNUM}\/%{MONTHDAY}\/%{YEAR} %{TIME}\s(?:AM|am|PM|pm)\s*\s\(%{TZ:tz}\)).*URL\=\"%{URI:url}\" ([^=]*)\=%{QUOTEDSTRING:src_ip}\s([^=]*)\=\"%{IPV4:dest_ipv4}\"\s([^=]*)\=%{QUOTEDSTRING:policy_rule} ([^=]*)\=%{QUOTEDSTRING:bloking_type} ([^=]*)\=%{QUOTEDSTRING:domain} ([^=]*)\=\"(?<server_alert_time>%{MONTHNUM}\/%{MONTHDAY}\/%{YEAR} %{TIME}\s(?:AM|am|PM|pm))\"\s([^=]*)\=%{QUOTEDSTRING:client_hostname} ([^=]*)\=\"%{BASE10NUM:reputation_score}/?"
        }
     }
}

output
{
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

The example of the output of logstash:

```
[2020-06-08T13:11:02,253][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/awesome_print-1.7.0/lib/awesome_print/formatters/base_formatter.rb:31: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
{
          "type" => "syslog",
    "@timestamp" => 2020-06-08T18:06:39.090Z,
       "message" => "<133>Jun 08 14:06:38 TMCM:EVT_URL_CONTENT_FILTERING Security product=\"OfficeScan\" Security product node=\"N/A\" Security product IP=\"xx.xx.xx.xx;xxxx::xxxx:xxx:xxxx:4490\" Event time=\"4/26/2020 7:33:36 AM (UTC)\" URL=\"http://blabnlabla.bla-blabla.intranet/SMS_MP/.sms_pol?DEP-Z0120105-ScopeId_B14503FF-F7AA-49EC-A38C-F50D813EEC6E/Application_2be50193-9121-4239-a70f-ba06ad7bbfbd.SHA256:6FF12991BBA769F9C15F7E1FA3E3058E22B4D918F6C5659CF7B976059082510D\" Source IP=\"\" Destination IP=\"xxx.xx.xxx.xx\" Policy rule=\"\" Blocking type=\"Web reputation\" Domain=\"bla-blabla\" Event time (local)=\"4/26/2020 3:33:36 AM\" Client host name=\"N/A\" Reputation Score=\"81\"",
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "xx.xxx.xx.xx",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

I have tried also `"\<133\>"` but it still appears. I have no idea what this <133> is.

P.S. I'm learning by myself since last 2 weeks.

Comment: This is normal, this is the syslog priority number, logstash has a pattern for it, just use `%{SYSLOG5424PRI }` to match the string `<133>` and not store anywhere.

Comment: Right on! Thank you very much !!!